# best data structure for storing

Tags: java, generics, data-structures, java-collections-api

I have a code requires to read a txt file where in each line there is a question and four possible answers saparated by tabs (the first one is the correct answer).
the question can repeat itself with different answers, for example: question of the type: "which is largest?"...

what is the most efficient data structure to store this data?
I thought of something like:

```
List<String> possibleAnswers = new LinkedList<String>();
Map<String, List<String>> map = new TreeMap<String, List<String>>();
```

and then extract the first answer (the correct one).

I'd like to hear more suggestions...

Comment: Most efficient for doing what?

Comment: It depends on what you have to do with the data. Do you have to print it out and check a user response? Or something else?

Comment: yes, there is a trivia question that appears on screen with 4 possible answers the user need to choose from.

Answer (score 0):

You better use: `Map<Integer,SomeObject> map = new HashMap<Integer,SomeObject>();`

The key is used to keep the line number from the text file